# How to get color of notification for Android?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-notifications, android-icons

Some notifications have their small notification icon appear as a badge in the bottom left corner of the big icon (See first, second and last notification).

[image]

However, post-Lollipop, the OS automatically sets a white color filter to the small icons and whenever I try to obtain them for display from my `NotificationListenerService`, they're returned in white. Is there any way I can extract the background color for the small icons, or obtain the small icon directly as colored drawables, as-is? Below is my code, which only returns completely white icons.

```
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    super.onNotificationPosted(sbn);

    Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;
    int smallNotiIcon = extras.getInt(Notification.EXTRA_SMALL_ICON);

    //Code to display obtained small icon in an imageView shows up as white
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color can be retrieved from a notification via the [color](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#color) public field:

```
Notification notification = sbn.getNotification();
// ARGB color set with the notification
int color = notification.color;
```

There is also [COLOR_DEFAULT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#COLOR_DEFAULT) as the default color of a notification, which you can use to see if a custom color is set at all.

Comment: I'm not sure why I didn't see this in the docs earlier. Thank you so much for taking your time to answer this. What you mentioned worked perfectly.